# How to stop avahi-daemon

Tags: linux, networking, debian, avahi

I'm trying to disable `avahi-daemon`. I tried to modify the file `/etc/default/avahi-daemon`, setting the `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` instead of `1`, but when I connect to a network it  starts anyway; is there no way to stop it?

I am trying to stop it because every time I connect  to a network it and `dhclient` starts it gives my NIC another address so I cannot access the network. I'm on a Debian machine.

Comment: The avahi dae/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/avahi-daemonmon can be started by `/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon` and ``, but this too is disabled if you have `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` in `/etc/default/avahi-daemon`. What version of the `avahi-daemon` package do you have? What is the full contents of `/etc/default/avahi-daemon`?

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo update-rc.d -f avahi-daemon remove
```

Comment: hi, and if i want to enable it again?

Comment: sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon defaults

Comment: cheers! I m going to try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rcconf` to disable it starting it from boot or you can manually remove it from autostartup with;

```
update-rc.d -f avahi-daemon remove
```

Only root can do this so use `sudo` if you are not root.

Comment: so you are saying that the file /etc/default/avhi-daemon is useless? in debian there is no rc.conf file :(

Comment: `rcconf` is a program :) And the default file is for changing the behaviour of `avahi-daemon` not to stop it.

Comment: ah ok I got it! I don't have that program so I have to change the behavior.. Cheers! I m going to try it